# ERROR: "No JSON object can be decoded" in Geopy when extracting lat, long from geocode_url

Tags: python, json, geocoding, geopy

I am using the following code:

```
from geopy import geocoders   

def main():
    gn = geocoders.GeoNames()
    city = 'roman'
    place, (lat, lng) = gn.geocode_url('http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q='+city+'&country=FR&featureClass=A&continentCode=&fuzzy=0.6')
    location, (lat, lon) = geocodes[0]
    print lat, lon
```

I want to print the first result returned from the Geopy website for a city, given the specific URL configurations (in France, feature = A, and fuzzy = .6)

However, I keep getting a "No JSON Object can be decoded" error from the above code.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use the JSON webservice:

```
url = 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=%s&country=FR&featureClass=A&continentCode=&fuzzy=0.6'
gn.geocode_url(url % city)
```

The proper way to add more params is to use `urlencode` and the url `geocode` uses:

```
from urllib import urlencode
params = {
    'q': 'roman',
    'featureClass': 'A',
    'fuzzy': '0.6',
    'country': 'FR'
}
gn.geocode_url(gn.url % urlencode(params))
```

Comment: How do I use the params feature if the city will change depending on the content of the text file it's traversing?

Comment: Change `'q':` as you were going to change your `city`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not directly familiar with geopy or the GeoNames database, but did you mean to be requesting something from [their web service](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html)?  The URL you've given seems to return a normal webpage rather than a JSON response, unless there's something tricky going on.

The API seems to have similar arguments, though it does require a username/account.  Perhaps you meant:

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=paris&country=FR&featureClass=A&continentCode=&fuzzy=0.6&maxRows=10&username=demo
```

Comment: `ws.geonames.org` doesn't require credentials.

Comment: Strangely, it appears to be deprecated in favour of `api.` for more than a year, but still works and is used by `geopy`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Interesting.  It looks like they're in the process of transitioning to new system (with rate limits), and the `ws.` hostname may be discontinued at some indeterminate point in the future: http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/2206.page